# how create second app iphone/ipad and publish?

Tags: ios, provisioning

What should I do if I want to make and publish a new application for iphone/ipad, when I already have an iphone/ipad app that was was published through itunes connect?  Do I need to create new app IDs and provisioning profiles?

sorry if my question just like the others, it's just that I was confused and wanted a detailed explanation.
Sorry my english bad.

Comment: Make the second one the same way you made the first one...

Comment: but who made ​​the first application was not me. All I ask is do I have to repeat from make App IDs, Provisioning Profiles?

Comment: In that case I will give you a tip about English:  When you say "I've" made a first application, it means you did it yourself.

Comment: You don't need to apologize for your English ability.  Just try to keep learning.  I know the pain of studying a foreign language well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need a unique App ID for every app you publish, and the provisioning profile must use that app ID.

Answer (score 0):

You should:

1. Code your app.
2. Make in Provisioning Portal App ID.
3. Create in Provisioning Portal distribution provisioning profile.
4. Download and install distribution provisioning profile to your Xcode.
5. Build and sign your app with your distribution provisioning profile.
6. Create app profile in iTunes Connect.
7. Upload to your app profile needed artwork and your app.
8. Wait for Apple review of your app.
9. Depending on review:

   - App review successful - Profit.
   - App review failed - modify your app and repeat steps 5, 7 and 8.

Comment: Slight mistake...should be *distribution* provisioning profile on steps 4 and 5.

Comment: thx for the answers, but i was curious. Will I be able use the bundle id is already registered and filling Bundle ID Suffix with bundle identifier existing app that I created on the xcode?? example: App ID: 38ASMxxxx.* Bundle ID Suffix: com.mycompany.secondApp or should I still register a new APP ID? sorry if I asked many questions